# Showing that $\frac{1}{x+y}$ is differentiable using definition of derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For every $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ the function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}$ is continuous and admits partial derivatives.
Then I need to show the remainder $\frac{E(h,k)}{||(h,k)||}$ vanishes as $(h,k)$ approaches to $(0,0)$, where $E(h,k) = f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} h - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} k$. Analyzing only the numerator

$E(h,k) = \frac{1}{x+h+y+k} - \frac{1}{x+y} + \frac{h}{(x+y)^2} + \frac{k}{(x+y)^2}$

I'm trying use $\frac{|\theta|}{\sqrt{\theta ^2 + \omega^ 2}} \leq 1$, ($\theta, \omega \in R$), to solve the limit

$lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{E(h,k)}{||(h,k)||}$

but I'm really stuck on it. Since the partial derivatives are continuous at every point but (0,0), $f$ is differentiable in the whole domain, so this limit is really equal to zero, but how to show it using the definition?

Comment: does it really continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$???

Comment: No it doesn't, as I tried to emphasize. And (h,k) is just an increment, it doesn't have any relationship with any point, right?

Comment: you write that it is continuous for every $(x,y)\in R^2$ and you asking in your title to show it is differentiable, the former  is false on the line $x=-y$ and therefore the later is impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I probably got confused when I wrote it. I'll correct it.

Comment: I've just realized that $E(h,k)$ can be reduced to $\frac{h^2 + 2kh + h^2}{(x+y+h+k)(x+y)}$, indeed the limit will be equal to zero.

Comment: yes, but you have typo (one of $h^2$ should be $k^2$) and anyway don't need it - see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $x\ne-y$, consider $a=x+y\ne0$ is fixed.
Now, turn into Polar Coordinates
$(h,k)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$ to get
$$\frac{E(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}=\frac{(h+k)^2}{a^2 \sqrt{h^2+k^2} (a+h+k)}
=\frac{r^2}{a^2 r (a+r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta))}
=\frac{r}{a^2  (a+r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta))}
$$

$$\lim_{h,k\to0}\frac{E(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}=
\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r}{a^2  (a+r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta))}
=\frac{0}{a^2  (a+\cdot(\cos\theta+\sin\theta))}=0
$$

Comment: Thank you, in the end I did not solve the limit using polar coordinates so it might be good let my attempt here:
$\frac{E(h,k)}{||(h,k)||}=\frac{h^2 + 2hk + k^2}{(h+x+k+y)(x+y) \sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}$ .

$lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{E(h,k)}{||(h,k)||}=\frac{1}{(x+y)^2} \cdot h \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \cdot 2k \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \cdot k \frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}$ .

Since the limit of product is the product of limits, the remainder is equal to zero. Again, thank you for you help.

Comment: Limit of product is a product of limits if and only if all the limits exists and finite. Btw, I fail to see why your expression above is correct,

Comment: Sorry again, the correct expression is: $lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{E(h,k)}{||(h,k)||}=\frac{1}{(x+y+h+k)(x+y)} (h \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} + 2k \frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} + k \frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}})$.

Then $lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{(x+y+h+k)(x+y)}= \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$, so it exists for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ . As both h and k are tending to zero and $\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \leq 1$, the last three terms have something limited multiplied by 0. Therefore the limit is equal to zero.

Comment: this one looks good